# Cancel CSS3 animation on hover

Tags: css, animation, hover

I'm looking for a way to completely cancel a CSS3 animation when the div is hovered.

Currently, the div has an animation that plays when the page loads, displaying the page menu for 3 seconds and then fading it out. In addition, the same div has :hover pseudo-class applied to it which displays the menu on hover.

The problem is that if a user hovers over the menu during the animation, it still fades out after 3 seconds, then re-appears because of the :hover pseudo-class. Is there a way to stop this from happening?  My goal is for the menu to display and fade out as normal if it is not hovered over - but, if the menu is hovered during those 3 seconds, for the animation to cancel and let the :hover pseudo-class control its behavior.

Here is the current keyframe, animation and hover code:

```
@keyframes navMenuSize{
  0%{max-width:100%;max-height:1400%;opacity:1;}
  70%{max-width:100%;max-height:1400%;opacity:1;}
  85%{max-width:100%;max-height:100%;opacity:1;}
  100%{max-width:0;max-height:100%;opacity:0;}
}

#navMenu.show{animation:navMenuSize 3s;}

#navMenu:hover{max-width:100%;max-height:1400%;opacity:1;transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;}
```

I tried the following as mentioned in my comment below:

```
#navMenu.show:hover{animation-play-state:paused;}
```

and

```
#navMenu.show:hover{animation-duration:0;}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zg6yR/2/

(Corrected jsFiddle thanks to Zeaklous)

Comment: Please provide some code (:

Comment: I tried the animation-play-state:paused - which works...but then when the user stops hovering the animation resumes, which results in the menu fading out (when the hover ends) then reappearing as the animation resumes, fading out after the original 3s.  I also tried animation-duration:0 on hover, which doesn't work because it causes the animation to trigger over and over on hover - for a duration of 0s - which creates a flickering effect.

Comment: @Zeaklous - code added :)

Comment: Pausing it like you did seems to be working for me (I changed `max-height` and `max-width` to `height` and `width`). http://cssdeck.com/labs/mr5zut7c

Comment: I use max-height and max-width because the height and width are variable. I only want it to be as wide / tall as it needs to be for the menu content - which changes. Would that change how the animation plays anyway?

Comment: Depends on how you have the height and width determined. Do you happen to have an example, perhaps on jsFiddle or something?

Comment: The height and width are determined by the content of the menu.  There can be anywhere from 3 items is 15, all with varying widths based on the length of the text. I don't have an account with jsFiddle - but would using height/width instead of max-height/max-width make any difference anyway? The problem is with the animation.  For example - I just took all the height/width commands out - so that it is only animation the opacity.  The problem is the same.

Comment: (You don't need an account with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) The height shouldn't have to do with it, but it could mean that they are in fact doing nothing anyway. And does the example I posted work for you?

Comment: Sorry - the example doesn't fit what the situation.  I updated the code above with the current :hover code as well.

Comment: How does the example not fit? It pauses on hover just as you described... I'm afraid you need to create a live demo, perhaps [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Added a jsFiddle, but for some reason the animation doesn't run when the jsFiddle loads, so it's not very helpful. The whole problem is that the animation runs when my page loads - which it's supposed to do - but there's no way to stop it from running if the user hovers over the menu during the animation.

Comment: [It does if you add browser prefixes](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Zg6yR/2/) (this one is for webkit). Now what's the problem? It pauses for me if I hover over it

Comment: In the jsFiddle I had tried the browser prefixes, but forgot the one on the keyframes - thanks! I see what you're saying, but it still doesn't behave properly. For example, if you move on/off the menu repeatedly it occasionally gets 'stuck' open or closed and doesn't respond. It also triggers the 3s animation every time it is hovered instead of fading out instantly when the menu is no longer hovered (which it does correctly if you remove the animation-play-state:paused line)

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use regular `transition`s for this?

Comment: @shsaw - the reason for using the keyframes animation is so that it can can run one time automatically when the page loads.

Comment: You can remove the animation class with a little javascript. [**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Zg6yR/4/). It's similar to the issues I discussed in [my CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/)

Comment: Also, you could use transitions and a class instead if you'd like. It'd use a line of js to add a class to it and likely use the `transition-delay` property, but if you only want it to run once it might be a viable option

Comment: @zeaklous - I do currently have a line of javascript that does the job...but I was hoping there'd be a pure CSS way. Seems like it should be possible!

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can add `animation:initial;` on `:hover` state.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  Although it did cause the menu to remain open on hover, it caused the menu to get stuck open occasionally and also caused the menu to 'jump' open on hover instead of animating open with the normal hover behavior.

Comment: `animation` should use with `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-`, `-o-` at first for browsers engines support them.